# Proof of the Balancing Vector Problem

Tags: optimization, expected-value

In the Balancing Vector problem

> Let $v_1,...,v_n$ be arbitrary unit vectors in $R^n$. How small can we
> make the norm of the combination $x_1v_1+···+x_nv_n$ by appropriately
> choosing $x_1,...,x_n ∈ \{−1,+1\}$?

> We claim that it can be assmall  as $\sqrt{n}$,  for  any  collection  of $v_i$s. Let $X_i,..., X_n$ bet independent random variables uniformly distributed in $\{-1, +1\}$

Below is the proof:

[image]

My question is how to deduce the line $\sum_{i,j} v_iv_jE[X_iX_j]$?

Isn't $E[X_iX_j] = E[X_i]E[X_j] = 0$? And it would reduce the whole equation to zero?

Comment: That only holds if all the random variables are independent.

Comment: @SeanRoberson ...which they are - you assume it!

Comment: @SeanRoberson Sorry about the confusion, I have updated the question.

Comment: $E[X_iX_j]$ equals to  $0$ if $i\neq j$ and equal to $1$ if $i=j$

Comment: @Leon Yeah but I can't get the result. $E[x^2]=\int^1_{-1}p(x)x^2dx=\frac{1}{3}x^3p(x)|^1_{-1}=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$. Did I make mistake in the equation?

Comment: @Kelvin_neverKnow, ah ok. You should notice that $X_i$ are discrete random variables, not continuous. So $E[X^2]=1^2.P(X=1)+(-1)^2 P[X=-1]=1/2+1/2=1$.